# How can I read and modify a variable using Rayon's par_iter in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

This code:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.5.0

fn main() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    items.push("hello");
    items.push("foo");
    items.push("bar");
    items.push("ipsum");

    let mut counter = 0;

    let results = items.par_iter().map(|item| {
        // do something time consuming with item
        counter += 1;
        print!("completed {} items\r", counter);
        0
    });
}
```

Produces an error:

```
warning: unused variable: `item`
  --> src/main.rs:12:41
   |
12 |     let results = items.par_iter().map(|item| {
   |                                         ^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_item`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: unused variable: `results`
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |     let results = items.par_iter().map(|item| {
   |         ^^^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_results`

error[E0594]: cannot assign to `counter`, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         counter += 1;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
```

Answer (score 5):

Rust prevents you here from having a data race by writing to the same variable from two different threads. You have a couple of options how to solve this. It really depends on the specific circumstances.

1. The simplest is to use a `Mutex` for `counter`. This allows you safe access to the same variable. Introducing the `Mutex` has the risk of eating up all the speedup of the parallel iterator, since everything will get sequential through the `Mutex` access. This can be acceptable if the runtime of the `map` is large and locking the `Mutex` short.
2. For the specific case of counters atomic types such as `AtomicI32` work well, but they are hard or impossible to use for more complex types.
3. Instead of directly aggregating on a single variable, the work can be done multiple times in parallel and then merged together. This is what the `reduce`-functions from rayon do. Each thread will have at least one counter and they will be merged together to produce a single final result.

Comment: Your answer would be better located on the duplicate.